# HTML 5 video not working in IE on Windows 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-7, html5-video

So I've read countless posts about this issue as it seems to be a common one but I've tried everything and I can find.

Here is the html

```
<video toggle-play autoplay loop>
  <source src="url.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="url.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I've added these MIME types to my .htaccess

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType video/mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv 
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I've tried changing the order of the different sources. I verified the video is using the H.246 codec for video and AAC codec for audio. I also made sure that my server isn't Gzipping the files it gives me.

The video works on all other browsers and all versions of IE in windows 10. Unfortunately the client needs it to work in windows 7.

Here is a working copy of the video if you want to look at it

http://ac.anthonyvespoli.com/html/home/home.html

Starting to get pretty frustrated. At the moment a flash fall back is not an option. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

The format  `.ogg` and `.webm` don't work in IE check http://caniuse.com/#search=video

but `.mp4`should  ... try comment the other one .. anche check better if the codec is the codec MPEG-4/H.264

Comment: I can see in the network tab that IE is pulling the .mp4 so I know I'm good there. I'm not getting any error messages either. I'm sure that the codec is H264 - MPEG4 - AVC

Comment: Have you tried to comment the other one (just for debug) and  have you check if there are error in browser console?

Comment: Yep and nothing changed. Still acted like it was working but wasn't rendering anything

Answer (score 0):

I found out that even though the codec was MPEG-4/H.264 that it was AC1 which apparently is not supported out of the box in windows 7. Converted the file to .avi and it works fine.